# Writing PHP Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am very new in mysql and I want to select a column by matching two values.

That is my query

```
$q = Select column1 from table where column1, column2=2 ;
```

Comment: So you want to match only `column2`? (Also try to learn some sql. Here is one resource for learning http://dwbi.org/database/sql)

Comment: You haven't tagged which language you are working in - are you working in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match the value of a particular column with a given value, use only that particular column in `WHERE`. For example,

```
$q='Select column1 from table where column2=2';
```

You can also put multiple columns if you desire. E.g.

```
$q='Select column1 from table where column2=2 AND column3="some other value"';
```

Also consider learning SQL. There are numerous resources available. Here is one: http://dwbi.org/database/sql

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main database APIs which are standard in PHP: mysqli_* and PDO.

Don't use mysql_* functions anymore - they are deprecated and prone to security problems.

For your SELECT query your code would look something like this in mysqli (copying the http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php example and modifying it):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 = 2";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    /* execute statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($column1);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf ("column1=%s\n", $column1);
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Using PDO would be similar, but you would find an example on http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Since it seems like SQL is your main challenge right now, I will strongly suggest getting some kind of GUI which will allow you to work on your queries in real time. The gold standard is phpMyAdmin, but there are several others out there as well.

Once you begin to get a handle on MySQL you will begin doing more queries and eventually you will want to do queries based on user input.  In other words, instead of looking at `WHERE column2 = 2` you will want the user to be able to enter whether he/she is interested in 2 or 4 or 7 and do the query based on the data they have entered through a form.  When you get to this point, be *absolutely* sure that you use prepared statements rather than just a query built in a string (above we just used a string). You can find examples of how to use prepared statements [here for mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [here for PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of statement in SQL:

select wantedcolumn from wantedtable where column1contents=valuewanted and column2contents=valuewanted

Here's an example.
Your table is called products, and each product has an ID number (called ID), an Item code (called ItemCode) and item name (called ItemName) and it contains this data:

```
ID    ItemCode   ItemName
1     123A       Screws
2     456B       Bolts
```

Now to select bolts based on matching two values, you use this SQL statement:

Select ItemName from products where ID=2 and ItemCode="456B";